# Adding password change field to form created by auth.profile()?

Tags: web2py

Is there a simple/recommended way to let the user change the password with the form generated by `auth.profile()`? I'm looking at the `def profile()` code in gluon/auth.py, and the `table_user[passfield].writable = False` line suggests that this form isn't used for changing the password, yet it seems like it should have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web2py's Auth system includes a separate `Auth.change_password()` method specifically for changing the password (rather than including just a single password field, it also includes fields for the old password and to confirm the new password). In the scaffolding application, it is accessible via /default/user/change_password, and it is included as a menu option in `auth.navbar()`.

If you want a single form that includes the profile and password change functionality, you will have to code your own custom action. You could simply create a form that includes all the user fields (including the password field) via `SQLFORM(db.auth_user)`. However, if you want to require and then validate the old password and a confirmation of the new password, you will need to customize the form and code the validation logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Depending on the design of a site, users will often find it far more intuitive to look for password change functionality in the profile form than to look for a separate menu item, which means that `Auth.change_password()` is not the optimal option. From the developer's point of view, the `auth.profile()` form is certainly more convenient than `SQLFORM(db.auth_user)`, but I can understand if the sentiment is not in favor of adding complexity to `auth.profile()` by presenting an option to add a password field.

Comment: I don't disagree. A pull request would probably be accepted if you want to add that option to the `auth.profile` functionality.

Comment: Thanks - I might go ahead and do that.